# How to export parent environment variable to bitbake shell task?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In a bitbake recipe, my **shell task** needs to export `http_proxy` to the process it calls. `http_proxy` is whitelisted in `BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE`, so the value exported from the shell which starts `bitbake` is available in the recipe as `${http_proxy}`.

To export it to the child task, I'm doing

`export http_proxy = ${http_proxy}
my_process`

This works, but leaves a feeling of redundant syntax to me. Is this the right way to pass the parent environment variable to a bitbake task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is proper way of accessing variables from environment in bitbake tasks, please see

<s>http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#exporting-variables-to-the-environment.</s>
And (in my opinion) *Bitbake* was designed to isolate from user environment and this - *redundant syntax* is the price for archive this feature.

Comment: The link is broken. Use https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.4.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#exporting-variables-to-the-environment